# find current moscow time using c#

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I'm trying to get local Moscow time in my .NET application.

Here is how far I went:

```cs
private static Dictionary<TimeZoneEnum, string> timeZoneDict = new Dictionary<TimeZoneEnum, string>()
{
    {TimeZoneEnum.RussiaStandardTime, "Russian Standard Time"}
};

public static DateTime GetDateTimeNowForTimeZone(TimeZoneEnum timezone)
{
    DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneDict[timezone]));
    return result;
}
```

Method GetDateTimeNowForTimeZone gives me GMT+3 time but now in russia there is GMT+4 time.
Is there anyu way to get robust solution for this issue in .net framework ?

Comment: According to this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx) that's correct

Comment: maybe you want to check if `IsDaylightSavingTime` and add one hour accordingly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Go straight to the source. I'd find a more robust time keeping system that doesn't flipflop between timezones.

Comment: Just had a look, and it appears that Russia has recently abandoned DST, which is probably why this is wrong.

Comment: @Gusdor Flip flop between timezones? How do you propose to deal with International times then?

Comment: @Alex the solution is not a programming one. How about governments just accept that arbitrarily messing with the time disrupts digital systems. It constitutes a breaking change. Russia 3.0? Either that or everyone uses GMT and just suck it up that it will be dark at 11am in some countries.

Comment: :D well i'm with you on that one. Nature is going apeshit lately anyways so I think this is a valid point.

Answer (score 10):

You need to patch your system. On my system (Windows 7 with all updates installed) it gives the correct time:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.Dump();
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time")).Dump();
```

output:

```
17/12/2013 09:11:08
17/12/2013 13:11:08
```

Microsoft has released [an update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2570791) a while ago to accomodate Russian DST law changes, you obviously don't have it.

*Dump() is an extension method provided by LINQPad. Equivalent of Console.WriteLine(<...>.ToString())

Comment: Now that I think about it this isn't going to help if the app is run on an outdated OS.

Comment: Well, problem is, this OS will have problems with time anyways. What help it will be if your program's clock shows 14:00, and windows' system clock shows 13:00? Better just show everything in system's local time - if the user got used to time being 1 hour off, he won't notice. For server/client interaction, it's UTC anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue will get resolved with a patch by Microsoft. They update the timezones periodically.

As far as I know for now all you can do is +1 the time.

Of course you could also go down the path of some web time service and request the time from it.

Comment: There is a bug in .net: According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx moscow time is GMT + 3 but actually it is + 4 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just the page didn't get updated - Russian Standard Time has GMT+4 now in .NET framework. There is a bug, however, in that old dates are converted incorrectly after this change

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug. The index is ahead of framework / OS updates. I was actually working on some timezone conversions on our system and discovered that in a space of a year they added two dozen timezones. Now there are .15 .30 .45 and offsets. I say now because I stumbled upon this recently mind you, this could have been the case for a while :)